# asp.net repeater and jQuery datables paging and check boxes not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, repeater

I'm using jquery datatables plugin along with asp.net repeater.  I but a check box in the first column of the repeater to allow a user to check which record they would like to save to the database.  I have the repeater, jquery plugin with paging working 100%.  The problem that I can't seam to resolve is that when I check a box on multiple page and hit submit, I'm only able to get the current page check box because all of the other checked boxes become unchecked.

.net Markup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var oTable;
$(document).ready(function () {

    oTable = $('#tblList').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bServerSide": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 7,
        "aaSorting": [[1, "asc"]],
        "bFilter": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "aoColumns": [
        /* other columns */null, null, null, null],
        "sDom": 'T<"toolbar">lrtip'
    });
});
</script>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPages" runat="server" Visible="false">
<asp:Repeater ID="rptList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RptList_ItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table id="tblList" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display">
                <thead>
                    <tr>                                
                        <th></th>                                
                        <th>Name</th>                                        
                        <th>Status</th>                            
                        <th>Modified</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                    <td style="width: 5%"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelected" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="Save_OnChecked" AutoPostBack="true" value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' /></td>
                    <td style="width: 47%"><%# Eval("Name")%></td>
                    <td style="width: 7%"><%# Eval("Status") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 25%"><%# ((DateTime)Eval("DateModified")).ToShortDateString() %></td>
                </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </tbody> 
        </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </asp:Panel>
```

On page load I call the following method and provide the list

```
public void DisplayList(List<MyPages> list)
    {
        rptList.DataSource = list;
        rptList.DataBind();
        pnlPages.Visible = true;
    }
```

This this method checks the boxes from the database

```
protected void RptList_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        string groupID = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]) ? Request.QueryString["id"] : string.Empty;
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            HiddenField pageID = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdnID");
            GroupPage groupPage = groupsPresenter.GetByKeys(new Guid(groupID), new Guid(pageID.Value));

            if (groupPage != null)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("chkSelected");
                chk.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

All of the above code works.  Here is where it stops working.  When a user checks a box the following code is executed.

```
protected void Save_OnChecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
        string id = chk.Attributes["value"].ToString();
    }
```

I noticed when debugging if I have 4 rows checked on the 1st page and I go to the 2nd page and uncheck a box the Save_OnChecked event is called and all of the check boxes on the home page become unchecked. so the Save_OnChecked is called 5 times total.

If I did not use the datatables paging and all of the records where on the first page it works just fine.  Hopefully this makes sense and I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

The jquery datatables plugin completely replaces all DOM elements when a paging event occurs. The previous page's data is completely removed, and therefore is lost.

You either need to send an AJAX post when the jQuery plugin changes pages, or save the data in your own JavaScript to preserve which checkboxes were selected on other pages. Either solution will work. It is up to you what style of saving you want to do. Auto-save at page change, or hold the list in memory until they hit the save/post button.

You would then send all the checked items that you saved in JavaScript memory, to your server via a custom AJAX/POST parameter that your C# code-behind (Save_OnChecked) would read in, instead of reading the form checkbox values directly, since those would only be showing the data for the most recently displayed page.

datatables plugin's fnPageChange ([API documentation](http://datatables.net/api)) doesn't appear to have an onchange-type hook to tie in your JavaScript function to save the data at the page change event in JS. You may have to modify the plugin to call your custom code. Or you could setup a jQuery delegate to watch all clicks on the page change links the plugin creates dynamically.